# R: How to pass values from a vector as args to gsub

Tags: r

gsub requires string arguments. But I'm want to process a whole array of string replacements. My sample code is as follows, but doesn't work

```
pairs <- c(c("a", "b"), c("e", "f"))
gsub("a", "b", "age")
#[1] "bge"

p1 <- pairs[1][1]
p1
#[1] "a"

p2 <- pairs[1][2]

gsub(p1, p2, "age")
#[1] NA
```

I'm sure this is fundamental thing about difference between vectors and strings but I don't know how to solve it. Apologies for what is doubtless a duplicate question but I've searched a lot of false leads in trying to google it

So with comment and answer from below I now understand:
Not really getting the "everything is a vector" I was making a false mental model that c("a", "b") turned characters into a vector of characters.
By extension I was thinking c(c("a", "b"), c("e", "f")) was creating a vector of vectors
But c("a", "b") is actually combining 2 single-element vectors into a single 2-element vector and by extension c(c("a", "b"), c("e", "f")) actually combines two 2-element vectors into a 4-element vector.
So matrices indeed is what I should have been working with in the first place.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Maybe `pairs` should be a matrix? `pairs <- cbind(c("a", "b"), c("e", "f"))` Then you can use matrix subsetting, `pairs[1,1]; pairs[1,2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have `pairs` as vector of character vectors. Ultimately if you check `pairs` it gives as

```
pairs
#[1] "a" "b" "e" "f"
```

So you can use them with single indexing

```
p1 <- pairs[1]
p2 <- pairs[2]

gsub(p1, p2, "age")
#[1] "bge"
```

Comment: OP does not create an `array`. A vector is not an array since it lacks a dimension attribute.